# How to allow an Android ListView to consume remaining space when inside a TableLayout

Tags: android

I am attempting to make a ListView inside a table consume all of the available vertical space minus the space needed for an EditText control.

I have set every attribute I can think of here to make it work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000">
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <ListView android:id="@+id/conversation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
    </ScrollView>
 </TableRow>

 <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00FF00">
     <EditText android:id="@+id/messagetext" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine|textImeMultiLine"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
 </TableRow>
```

I must be missing something, as the result is a fully filled horizontal, but both the ListView and EditText appear to be behaving as if their attributes were wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're using a TableLayout? I'm not very familiar with using them yet, but what you're trying to accomplish is simple with a RelativeLayout. Also, you don't need to place the ListView within a ScrollView, the ListView handles scrolling on its own. Here is an example of how you could accomplish this using a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine|textImeMultiLine"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:alignParentBottom="true"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/conversation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_above="@id/message_text"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way, you first define the EditText to take up a certain amount of space (wrap_content, in this instance). Then, you define the ListView to fill the remaining space with fill_parent. Adding android:layout_above="@id/message_text" aligns the bottom edge of the ListView with the top edge of the EditText view.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have been missing an attribute android:layout_weight on the top TableRow.  Evidently, anything over 2 makes it consume the rest of the vertical real estate.  Can anybody explain why the special treatment for TableRows?

Comment: You don't need a value of 2 four your layout_weight. If it is the only element attributed with it then you can assign it a value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ListView` inside of `ScrollView`, because ListView manages it's own vertical scrolling. Doing so will kill all optimization's done by the `ListView`

And don't anwser to your own posts. Rather edit your initial questions or add an comment.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to answer your own question if you've solved it.